CoreWebView.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping and msal login
I host a wpf webview2 control and call CoreWebView.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping so I can load html amd javascript in a plugin to my main program to use the microsoftsharepoint sdk and filePicker v8.   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/?view=odsp-graph-online.
If I let it pop up a login then it shows it cannot find the page as it tries to load the page from the virtual host, but seems not to be able to find it.  Which is annoying it does however allow a login.  If I make the login inline the I get the error

refused to frame 'https://testsite-my.sharepoint.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.office365.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com engage.cloud.microsoft *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.microsoft365.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com *.dynamics.com *.microsoft.com onedrive.live.com *.onedrive.live.com securebroker.sharepointonline.com".

I did try making another webviewer2 popup and set the virtual host on that, but then it did not redirect back properly to the first window whereas the default implementation of a new window does.
Any ideas without making a webserver just to serve the picker page and javascript locally? There can be multiple instances of my program running too otherwise I probably could just embed a httplistener.

To resolve the login issue with WPF WebView2 control and Microsoft SharePoint SDK/FilePicker v8, consider handling Content Security Policy directives or serving the picker page locally without setting up a separate web server.
